# Is my logical quantifier representation of "The natural number n > 1 is a prime" correct?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

$$ \forall p \forall q [(p > 1 \land q > 1) \implies (n \ne pq) ]$$
I feel like it's correct but still want to make sure.

Comment: It's correct. I'd only add this: $\forall p \in \mathbb N \; \forall q \in \mathbb N$. You can also think of the contrapositive.

Comment: Thank you. The suggestion of thinking the contrapositive is helpful :)

Comment: Nice! Welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Alternatively, $$\forall p\;\forall q\; \big( p\in\mathbb N\land q\in\mathbb N \land n =pq\implies p = 1 \lor q = 1 \big).$$